# ADB echo gives "No such file or directory"

Tags: android, echo, adb

I'm trying to write text to a file with adb and stumble on some problems.

If I do it in two steps, like this:

```
adb shell 
echo "hello" > /sdcard/temp/hello.txt
```

it works. But if I try to do it on one row like this:

```
adb shell echo "hello" > /sdcard/temp/hello.txt
```

I get "No such file or directory". Must I change the path in some way? I'm   going to call on this from another script I have must have it on one row.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to quote the entire script you'd like executed:

```
adb shell "echo \"hello\" > /sdcard/temp/hello.txt"
```